# React to events on custom Dialog - android

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, events, android-intent

this is acceuilActivity :

```
public class AcceuilActivity extends FragmentActivity {

private GoogleMap mMap;
Button handle,b1,b2,b3,b4;
RadioGroup choixSignalGroup;
RadioButton ChoixSignalButton;
Button signaler,annuler;
SlidingDrawer slidingDrawer;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_acceuil);

    SupportMapFragment mapFrag = (SupportMapFragment) this.getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);

    mMap = mapFrag.getMap();    

    handle = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.handle);
    slidingDrawer = (SlidingDrawer) findViewById(R.id.slidingDrawer1);

    b1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.b1);
    b1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            Dialog d = new Dialog(AcceuilActivity.this);
            d.setContentView(R.layout.dialog_signal);
            d.setTitle("Signalement");
            choixSignalGroup = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.radioGroup1);
            signaler = (Button) findViewById(R.id);
            d.show();
        }
    });

    b2 = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.b2);
    b3 = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.b3);
    b4 = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.b4);   
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.acceuil, menu);
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}    
}
```

this is dialog_signal :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/LinearLayout1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
    <RadioGroup
        android:id="@+id/radioGroup1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radio1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Encombrement" />
        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radio2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Accident" />
        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radio3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Danger" />
        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radio4"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Barrage" />
        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radio5"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Traveaux" />
    </RadioGroup>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/signaler"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Signaler" />
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/annuler"
            android:layout_width="110dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Annuler" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

when i called radio group from the custom dialog layout (dialog_signal) it worked but when i tried to call a button (signaler) from the same layout it didn't work ! please help

Answer (score 0):

Create dialog like this :

```
public void createDialog() {
    Dialog dialog = new Dialog(YourActivity.this);

    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.custom_dialog_layout);
    dialog.setTitle("Select");
    dialog.setCancelable(true);

    final Spinner spn = (Spinner) dialog.findViewById(R.id.spinner1);

    dialog.show();
}
```

Assume that there is a spinner in the custom xml layout. Use dialog.findViewById(), to find the id from the layout. You can create listener methods below that code.

As far as putting it in which activity is concerned, you have to determine that. Wherever you want to launch the dialog from, simply call the method. But, do remember to create this method in the activity, from which you intend to launch the dialog.

Use RadioGroup the same way as spinner, and you'll be ready to roll.

Comment: thanks but my question is how to launch another activity depending on the choice on the dialog, the buttons of this dialog i declare them on any class i want ?

Comment: Declare this buttons as i've declared spinner. Declare everything that is in dialog layout, in the method. Write onCLickListener code in the same method also.

Comment: You need to define a radiogroup and two radio buttons in the layout. Do you how to implement them and get value from the radiobutton?

Comment: thanks a lot. i got it :) 
for the radio buttons , yes i knw how to manipulate them : i created an xml file which contains the dialog.
thanks again

Comment: Please, do remember to mark it, if this answer helps you. If any issue occurs, let it be known here in comments.

Comment: Why are you initializing button inside onClick()? You're creating dialog on onCLick() ?

Comment: yes, on the main view i have 4 buttons and if i click on b1 it should appear a dialog that contains these buttons. is it wrong like this ?

Comment: apparently i forgot to add dialog.show() in my answer. Add that line at the end, after you're done intializing and setting events for views of dialog. I've edited it now. Please check

Comment: I saw your screenshot. You haven't written anything after R.id. , so there is error there. What exactly is the issue? Please explain.

Comment: the problem was with the IDs, after i tried to clean and rebuild the project to update IDs now the R.java has disappeared and i'm trying to get it back
ps : thnx for your note but i already did it

Comment: Got R.java back? If you can't, check Console, it'll tell you where in XML layout error is.

Comment: but i want to ask you if this is right to initiallize custom dialog's buttons and its onClickListeners inside the onClickListener of the button of the main activity ?

Comment: my consl and logcat are empty ! when i click on run project it says to me that there is errors but nothing shows in the consol

Comment: It's all right to initialize like that. Regarding R.java, remember what was the last change you made before everything went haywire. If there is a problem with even a single ID or resource, it may not generate R file. Eclipse is such a pain in the bum in that area particularly.

Comment: thnx very much. now i will try to fix everything so i can generate the R.java . 
very rich experience for my first project in android :)

Comment: R.java harasses me still. Let's wait for Android studio. It should be the game-changer, dumping the eclipse, once and for all.